# PHP: Search through page source line by line for one parameter of an object

Tags: php, regex, string, search

I have the **player.html**

```
<div class="playerPane ">
    <object width="100%" height="100%" id="swf5deL" name="swf5deL" data="player.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
        <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
        <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
        <param name="flashvars" value="type=video&amp;image=thumb.jpg&amp;file=d05aba8ce">
    </object>
</div>
```

I would like to set up a script that will go though this snippet and be able to pick out the file number "d05aba8ce" inside of the parameter flashvars.

Any suggestions on how to best do this? Would it be best to use regex for this? Or is there a PHP function specifically designed for it?

Hope someone can help, thanks!

Comment: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: Take a look at one of the available dom parsers for php instead of approaching with a regex. This gives you a structured access to all details of the "page" instead of a simple string based search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Wrikken and @CurtisW for their advice. It's where I got the answer I needed

in **player.html**, I've now got

```
<div class="playerPane ">
    <object width="100%" height="100%" id="swf5deL" name="swf5deL" data="player.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
        <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
        <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
        <param name="flashvars" value="type=video&amp;image=thumb.jpg&amp;file=d05aba8ce">
    </object>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function linkToVideo()
    {
        var flashvarLink=document.getElementsByTagName("param").item(3).getAttribute("value");
        window.location.href = "/scripts/flashvars_processor.php?" + flashvarLink;
    }
    setTimeout(linkToVideo,15000);

</script>
```

And then, in **flashvars_processor.php**, it's simple enough to grab the "file" attribute via $_GET:

```
<?php
    $filedownload = $_GET['file'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use domdocument to search within the specific dom element. However I wrote both a regex  and domdocument snippet for you that would work for you.

String Input:

```
<?
$string = '<div class="playerPane ">
<object width="100%" height="100%" id="swf5deL" name="swf5deL" data="player.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
    <param name="flashvars" value="type=video&amp;image=thumb.jpg&amp;file=d05aba8ce">
</object>
</div>';
?>
```

Regex:

```
<? 
preg_match_all("#type=video&amp;image=thumb.jpg&amp;file=([a-z0-9]+)\"#",$string,$out);
$filename = $out[1][0];
$echo $filename;
?>
```

DomDocument:

```
<?
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($string);
$elems = $dom->getElementsByTagName('param')->item(3)->getAttribute('value');
parse_str($elems,$pieces);
$filename = $pieces['file'];
echo $filename;
?>
```

Comment: .. or use `parse_str` for that those last steps.

Comment: Thanks @Wrikken ! `$string` is a piece of embedded video player that is generated by js, and it takes a few seconds before it gets displayed. Right now, your suggestion is giving me `Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttribute() on a non-object`. I figure this is  because `loadHTML` is able to grab content _before_ the player is generated. Is there a way to sort of delay its processing, or maybe wait until fully loaded?

Comment: @jeffimperial, would you need the file id server side? If so you'd need to send the generated dom to the PHP file via javascript, else just use JS to parse the filename

Comment: @jeffimperial: that sounds more like the video is added with javascript. If you download the source HTML, is the video element there or not? If not, you may have to alter your requirements to sort-of parse the javascript that generates it. Otherwise, you don't need PHP but almost a full blown browser you can query (Selenium might work for thata, but with _huge_ overhead).

Comment: @CurtisW need to be able to grab the value, add it to a CSV file.

Comment: @Wrikken indeed, video player is added by js. When viewing page source, the video element is not there. Only when I inspect the page with dev tools do I see the embed code.

Comment: You guys were right. I needed a browser to be able to collect the param value I needed. So I added an additional js at the bottom of the page that waits until all elements are loaded, then grabs the value I need, and then throws it out to a php that will process the value. I'm sorry for having to "answer my own question", which I only derived from your advice. I think I'll put it up here if anyone else needs something similar. Thanks guys!